# Subdivision Modifier creates some weird vertices that can't be selected

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

Subdivion surface creates vertices like things.

when z to solids it also get showed.
I'm just a beginner. tried to scale down,and ctrl+a, it gets worse.
tutorial video didn't show such problems. Help to start learning blender.

[image: subdivion surfacae creates vertices like things.]

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=ZkD7KSLo" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ZkD7KSLo/)

Comment: I didn't have any issue when opening your file, maybe try to import your model in a new file.